# How can i determine if the user is signed in or not , and how to sign the user out from google+ api?

Tags: android

I used google+ api in my android app to implement sign in with google ,When I close the sign in activity by calling `finish()` method, and start a new activity .

In the new activity I have a sign out button .

I want to sign him out  if he clicks the button, I know the code to sign out 
but it seems that the code needs an object from GoogleApiClient as written below

```
private void signOut() {
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                // ...
            }
        });
}
```

From where I can get this object ? 
send it from the previous activity , initialize new one , or what should i do ?
and how to determine if the user is already signed in or not ?

Comment: You can create a base class and move your GoogleApiClient object initailization code to that class. Inherit all your activity from this base class which you created and make the object protected so that you can have the access to it

Comment: You can initialize the new GoogleApiClient as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
private void signOut() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        }
}
```